# Cant join 3 tables as they are not related to each other

Tags: sql, sql-server

i need a code to get Fullname, Contact, City and House Details of the tenants who have not referred even once*/
now my profile contains 
first_name,last_name,email,phone,[city(hometown)],created_at,gender,referral_code

Tenace.history have 
move_in_date,move_out_date,rent,bed_type,move_out_reason,house_id,profile_id

dbo.Referrals have 
referrer_bonus_amount,referral_valid,valid_from,valid_till,referrer_id

dbo.Houses have
house_type,bhk_details,bed_count,furnishing_type,beds_vacant

dbo.Addresses have
    name,description,city,pincode,house_id

dbo.Referrals have 
referrer_bonus_amount,referral_valid,valid_from,valid_till,referrer_id

Now i need a way to join profile id with house id and only place its available is tenance_history and referal_id. But I am not able to link them. 
The best code i came up with is below is the below one but has syntax error.

```
select dbo.Profiles.first_name +' '+ dbo.Profiles.last_name as full_name, dbo.Addresses.name,DBO.Addresses.city,dbo.Addresses.description, 
dbo.Houses.house_type, DBO.Houses.bhk_details, DBO.Houses.furnishing_type, dbo.Houses.bed_count, DBO.Houses.Beds_vacant,
dbo.Referrals.referrer_id
 from Addresses 
 inner join
 dbo.Houses, dbo.Profiles
 on
 dbo.Houses.house_id = dbo.Addresses.house_id
 inner join
 dbo.Referrals.referrer_id, dbo.Profiles.profile_id
 on 
dbo.Referrals.referrer_id=dbo.Profiles.profile_id=  
where dbo.Referrals.referrer_id != dbo.Profiles.profile_id
```

Comment: You are inner joining on Referrals.referrer_id and Profiles.Profile_id and afterwards you only want to see where they don't match. This will give you zero results.

Comment: You don't join tables with `,`

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the tenants who have never referred the below query helps. Assuming that referrer_id and profile_id has foreign key relationship.

```
`SELECT *  ------ include required columns instead of *
FROM dbo.addresses a
JOIN dbo.houses h ON a.house_id = h.house_id
LEFT JOIN dbo.referrals r ON h.profile_id = r.referrer_id
WHERE r.referrer_id IS NULL`
```